# How do I query multiple nested objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have documents that look like this:

```
{
    items: {
        a: {value: "1111"},
        b: {value: "2222"}
    }
},
{
    items: {
        a: {value: "3333"},
        b: {value: "1111"}
    }
}
```

How do I write a query that will return any document with `items.*.value = "1111"`?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
await Model.find({
    "items.$**.value": "1111"
});
```

Is it possible to query for multiple nested objects with `value === "1111"`?

This is the only thing I can think of but I would rather not write each line:

```
await Model.find({
    $or: [
        {"items.a.value": "1111"},
        {"items.b.value": "1111"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: You should need an aggregation query to convert the key-value pair into array of objects, `$match` and then convert back to key-value pair. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wcDnTfst-cB)